# I can't figure out how to fix TypeError: can't concat str to bytes mean

Tags: python, byte

I wrote a function to see encrypt a given text file. The below code is a small portion of the function.

```
            #pad it before encrypting it
            elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                chunk += ' ' * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)
            #write encrypted data into output file
            out_file.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))
```

Whenever I try to use the function I get an error that points to the last line saying 
"TyprError: can't concat str to bytes". I'm not sure what I need to do in order to fix this error. I've tried a few things and they end leading me into more similar errors. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. 
The encryptor is below.

```
encryptor  = PKCS1_OAEP.new(pub_key)
```

Comment: You probably need `b' '`, not `' '`.

Comment: @chepner I tried this before and it gave me TypeError: must be str, not bytes

Comment: Does `encryptor.encrypt` expect a string? It's impossible to tell from the code you have posted. But if `type(chunk)` is `bytes`, then you have to use `b' '` to start, because `+` doesn't support concatenating a `bytes` object with a `str` object. The other error is another problem.

Comment: encryptor  =PKCS1_OAEP.new(pub_key), this is the encryptor. its just the public key that will be used in order to encrypt the data

Comment: Can the multiplier in your padder be negative?

Comment: @jaywinston what difference would that make? just wondering

Comment: That would return an empty string. I don't think it would affect your issue. It's just something I noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Your encryption method `encryptor.encrypt()` very likely accepts `bytes` as argument, not `str`. It also returns `bytes` very likely. So I suggest you to use the `encode/decode` methods as follows (example of `utf-8` coding):

```
 out_file.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I tired this as well and it gave me a TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: @EddieWhite That's because your `encrypt` method returns a `bytes` value: you have to decode it... I have updated my post.

Comment: When I decode it, it takes be back full circle to the cant concat str to bytes error again

Comment: Nvm it put the decode in the wrong spot. It still gave me an error but its different from the one before.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix and match incompatible data types. Here is an example that will throw the same error:

```
str1 = bytes(123)
str2 = str(123)
str1 + str2
```

Go through your example and find where you are trying to concat a bytes value to a str value and make them match types.